# EF Context not keeping values after adding entity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

**Edit** Is this post lacking sufficient information to get some guidance?

I have this method to insert an entity into the database:

```
public void Insert(T entity)
{
    _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I inspect `entity` before adding it to the context, my `CustomerRole` field is there. Once the add has taken place, the context doesn't seem to have it. Because of this, I am receiving this error:

> Entities in 'CcDataContext.Customers' participate in the
>   'Customer_CustomerRole' relationship. 0 related
>   'Customer_CustomerRole_Target' were found. 1
>   'Customer_CustomerRole_Target' is expected.

These images show what I mean:

**Inspecting my entity**
[image]

**Inspecting the context**
[image]

Can anyone explain this behaviour and what I can do about it?

This is the structure of my classes (cut down for brevity):

```
public class Customer : BaseEntity
{
    public CustomerRole CustomerRole { get; set; }
}

class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        HasRequired(t => t.CustomerRole)
            .WithMany(t => t.Customers);
    }
}

public class CustomerRole : BaseEntity
{
    private ICollection<Customer> _customers;
    public ICollection<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return _customers ?? (new List<Customer>()); }
        set { _customers = value; }
    }
}
```

I can confirm that customer map is being added to the configuration and my database is built in line with them.

This is the call I am making which does the insert:

```
public Customer InsertGuestCustomer()
    {
        var customer = new Customer();
        CustomerRole guestRole = GetCustomerRoleByName("Guest");
        if (guestRole == null)
            throw new Exception("Customer Role is not defined!");
        customer.UserName = "";
        customer.EmailAddress = "";
        customer.Password = "";
        customer.IsAdmin = false;
        customer.CustomerRole = guestRole;
        _customerRepository.Insert(customer);
        return customer;
    }
```

I have no other data in my database, this would be the first customer record and only one CustomerRole. My `Customer` table has a Foreign Key pointing to my `CustomerRole.Id` table / column.

Comment: What is the origin of the `Customer` + `CustomerRole`? How were they created? The expected behavior would be that the `CustomerRole` has an `Added` state. Somehow relationship fixup decides that the relationship should be broken, but it's hard to tell why without knowing what happened before this `Insert` call. Maybe there are primitive foreign key properties with conflicting values?

Comment: @GertArnold - I appreciate your comments, thanks. I have added more information to the post below the images. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Looking at your code I suspect that `guestRole` is attached to a different context than the context in `_customerRepository`. You must (somehow) make sure that it is attached to the customer's context (state: Attached) before saving changes. Or set a primitive RoleId value in `Customer`.

Comment: @GertArnold I have just looked at this and both Contexts are the same from what I can see. I look at the context used to open `guestRole` and it shows 1 `CustomerRole`, I then look at the context for the `_customerRepository` and it shows the same `CustomerRole` open. Getting a little confused now. Will have to keep digging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your navigation properties as `virtual` and initialize the collection property in the entity constructor rather than from the property getter.

```
public class Customer : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual CustomerRole CustomerRole { get; set; }
}

...

public class CustomerRole : BaseEntity
{
    public CustomerRole()
    {
        Customers = new List<Customer>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; protected set; }
}
```

In your Customers property, you were returning a new List in the getter when the backing field was null, but you never assigned this to your backing field.

Comment: Excellent, your edited versions sorted it out. Many thanks for your time. I thought it must of been something odd on my end (trying to be to damned clever it seems).

Comment: Just checked other areas that are working and this would explain it. They are written like this: `get { return _rolePermissions ?? (_rolePermissions = new List<RolePermission>()); }` (notice the var assignment). Sigh. Long day.

Comment: I have never seen a case where either a public setter or a private backing field on a collection property provides any benefit. If you declare the setter as protected and initialize it during construction, this allows you to manipulate the collection fully (using Clear, Add, Remove, etc), allows the dynamic proxies to set the value when they need to, and you can trust the value will never be null.